# Need helpeople with website design

Tags: web

I am newish to coding websites, I've done it before but I want to start getting more advanced. And I need some help, I am attempting to make a website that looks like this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/tcwOK.jpg
Ihave the logo and can do any gfx.
Ok let me give a summery, I want to have the navigation bar around the logo likeep shown, and the quick news could be a feed from a forum or something and I would like to have the navigation bar on all pages not including forum.
I am not asking for you to code it for me but simply just help and general tips.

Thank you very much for reading,
Nick

Answer (score 0):

You should have the navigation at the head of every web page. Think of your users!